# View rendering as blank in Zend Framework action

Tags: php, zend-framework

```
<?php

class SignupController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
function indexAction()
{

    if ($this->_request->isPost())
    {
        echo "Your email address is: " . $this->_request->getPost('email');
    }

    $this->render("signup");

    }

}
```

This is my controller

this is my view

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="/signup" method="post">

    Email: <input name="email" type="text" />
    <input name="btnSubmit" value="Click me" type="submit" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

when I tried to run the view 
I am getting result
blank/signup
why this happens
please rectify that error, and tell me the reason for that error

Comment: try displaying the error using error_reporting(E_ALL)

Comment: Please remove your localhost link brother

Comment: try writting POST instead of post in the HTML file. This seemed to broke some code on my machine on some browsers sometimes

Answer (score 0):

If you are using signup view then replace your render code from this :-

```
$this->_helper->viewRenderer('signup');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with else:

```
    if ($this->_request->isPost()) {
        echo "Your email address is: " . $this->_request->getPost('email');
    } else {
        $this->render("signup");
    }
```